# conditional probability and law of total probability

Tags: probability

I have a simple question regarding the conditional probability. Suppose $U$ is a random variable with uniform distribution over some set $S$, and let $V$ be a random variable over $S$ with arbitrary distribution. Let $f: S \to T$ be some function, where $T$ is some other set. Is the following correct:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
P(f(V)=t) &= \sum_v P(V=v) P(f(V)=t \mid V= v) \\
&\leq \max_v P(V=v)\, |S| \, \sum_v \frac{1}{|S|} P(f(V)=t \mid V= v) \\
&= \max_v P(V=v)\, |S| \, P(f(U)=t)\end{array}$$

The first equation follows by the law of total probability. The inequality follows by definition of max. I am not completely sure by the last equality, since as far as I understand $P(f(V)=t | V= v) = P(f(v)=t)$ is either $0$ or $1$, so I am a bit confused over what the probability is taken here (everything seems fixed). It would be great if you could give me some intuitive explanation why this is correct for the last equality.

Thanks a lot!
Greg

Comment: What is $U$ in $f(U)$ ?

Comment: Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Yes, see my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $P(f(V)=t \mid V= v)$ is either $1$ or $0$, we can write $\sum_v P(f(V)=t \mid V= v) = |A_t| $ where $A_t\subset S$ is the pre-image set of $t$ over $f(\cdot)$, i.e. $A_t =\{v\in S :f(v)=t\}$. Hence

$$\frac{\sum_v P(f(V)=t \mid V= v)}{|S|}= \frac{|A_t|}{|S|}=P(f(U)=t)$$

where the last equation arises because $U$ has uniform distribution over $S$.